# Application pool fails to start 'invalid identity' Error 1021

Tags: windows, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I've create an application pool with another user than 'NETWORK SERVICE' and fails to start.
In the event viewer I can see something like:

```
Event Type>: Warning
Event Source: W3SVC
Event Categor: None
Event ID: 1021
Description: The identity of application pool, 'Test Pool' is invalid. If it remains  invalid when the first request for the  application pool is processed, the  application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error  number.
```

What I've missed?

Comment: I've found it, it is as simple as adding the new user to the IIS_WPG group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it, it is as simple as adding the new user to the IIS_WPG group

Comment: Thanks!!  This worked for us too, but the weird thing was that we had to refresh the app Pool multiple times after getting the same error, then it started working.